# Can ASP.NET Identity FinderUser search on other parameters

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET Identity (v2.2.1) to manage my user database. My requirements are such that some users do not have a password. Just a First Name, Last Name, and Email address. Is it possible to create a version of FindUser() that searches on the `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Email` fields instead of `username` and `password`? If so any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, this should be pretty simple, something along these lines:

```
public List<ApplicationUser> UsersSearch(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    var users = dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == firstName && u.LastName = lastName).ToList();

    return users;
}
```